# Firebase doesn't create the account after filling the account creation activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After completing the account creation activity firebase doesn't create the account and shows that no new users have been created. I have looked at the documentation on the firebase website and I can't seem to understand what I am missing.
Below I have the function that is responsible for account creation.

I have also checked that android studio has the latest versions of all the firebase SDK's and that I have configured the project with the firebase assistant properly.

In my onClick function is also affected as this comes up in my exception error.
I highlighted the problematic lines in both my registerAction() and onClick() functions.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.registerButton:
        registerAction(EmailField.getText().toString(), PasswordField.getText().toString()); **Error handles here**
        break;

        case R.id.loginButton:
            loginAction(EmailField.getText().toString(), PasswordField.getText().toString());
            break;

        case R.id.resendConfirmationButton:
            confirmAction();
            break;

        case R.id.resetButton:
            resetAction();
            break;

        case R.id.forgotButton:
            forgotPasswordAction(EmailField.getText().toString());
            break;

        case R.id.showLoginButton:
            showLoginAction(true);
            break;

        case R.id.showRegisterButton:
            showRegisterAction(true);
            break;
    }

}
 private void registerAction() {
      String email = EmailField.getText().toString();
      String password = PasswordField.getText().toString();

// This sends the users email and password to firebase to save as a token.
    Log.d(TAG, "Create user account: " + email);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() { **Error also occurs here**
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
            // This is called when the user registration as expected.
            Log.d(TAG, "CreatedUserWithEmail:success");
            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this, "Registration was successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        } else {
            // In the event that user authentication fails.
            Log.w(TAG, "CreatedWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(AuthenticationActivity.this, "User registration has failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Upon running the code Android Studio returns with this exception:

```
   Process: com.lyfeforcelabs.nitelyfe, PID: 6103
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source:5)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source:247)
    at com.lyfeforcelabs.nitelyfe.AuthenticationActivity.registerAction(AuthenticationActivity.java:143)
    at com.lyfeforcelabs.nitelyfe.AuthenticationActivity.onClick(AuthenticationActivity.java:82)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @AlexMamo just added the exception result when I test the code

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo just made the edits with the problematic code

Comment: @Blackmamba here are my dependencies firebase core and firebase auth

Comment: check this You wrote wrong Case :

case R.id.registerButton:
        registerAction();
        break;

Comment: there's no peramenters for this method @TimmyT

Comment: I don't understand how this works at all.  The registerAction function takes no arguments, yet you have a line that passes it two arguments.  That shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote wrong Case :

```
case R.id.registerButton:
        registerAction();
        break;
```

Explanation :

Your Switch case contains `registerAction` method / function which does not take any parameter.

I suggest in `registerAction` put Null check if user does not input the values. Application will crash

Comment: Ok interesting observation, but I don't exactly understand how this helps my problem

Comment: @TimmyT your problem solved ? or still there's error. If there's error. i'll solve error first then provide explanation.

Comment: can you give me an example of what I can do to resolve the switch case issue?

Comment: Either provide parameter in function or method or Remove the parameter from it.